# An email System outside the SUD is considered an actor while receiving an email from it?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

In a use-case I've included a step in which the SUD(System under development) sends an email externally. 
Does the email system receiving that email is considered an actor? Or even a stakeholder?
According to my studies, everything that interacts anyhow with the SUD is an actor, but in this case I have some doubts.

Anybody that can give some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Anything that interacts with the SUD is considered to be an actor. It does not matter how this interaction takes place. So just connect that email system as actor with the according use case bubble inside the SUD.

There is some sort of convention to place a primary actor (one that starts an interaction) to the left of the SUD boundary and secondary ones (those being triggered by the SUD) on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

is your system only interacts with the email-service by sending mail to it the email-service is only a secondary actor

if your system can receive a mail from the email-service that one is a (primary) actor